# Base64 encoded String that contains exclamation points causing exception

Tags: c#, encoding, base64

Unfortunately, I cannot post the string as it contains sensitive data. I have created an API that is in use at my company. We have a partner that is attempting to use said API. In a part of the JSON there we expect a base64 encoded string of a digitally signed XML file. When I parse the JSON and try to decode the Base64 string, the API throws an exception.

> System.FormatException occurred HResult=0x80131537
>   Message=The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
>
> Source=mscorlib
>
> StackTrace:
>   at System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char* startInputPtr, Int32 inputLength, Byte* startDestPtr, Int32 destLength)
>   at System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)
>   at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
>   at Base64Decoding.Program.Main(String[] args) in

I have tried taking the raw XML and encoding it on 3 different machines, including a Linux system using Python, I have gotten the exact same Base64 string each time. The string that I receive does not match his string.

This is the only partner we work with that has ever had an issue with the encoding and not matter what I have tried, I cannot duplicate his results encoding the signed XML file. When I try to decode his Base64 using [an online decoder](https://www.base64decode.org/), it displays an error. But when I click the decode button, ***it actually downloads the correctly decoded XML***!

[image: error decoding due to malformed string]

When I use my encoded string of the same file, it does not display the error, it displays the decoded XML in the 'live view' box and downloads the correct XML when I click the decode button.

Does anyone have any idea what might cause `System.Convert.ToBase64String()` to output a string with exclamation points in it? To my understanding that should not be an allowed character in Base64. I have tried 64 vs. 32 bit, I have tried every version of the .Net Framework to back to 2.

Comment: Your link is broken, but why do you think submitting Base64 to a random webpage is more secure that posting to Stack Overflow?

Comment: If your encoded string does not match the customer's encoded string. It seems pretty obvious that this is a problem with your customer's encoding process, or their process for transmitting the encoded string to you...

Comment: The fine print on that online page seems useful: _decoding of binary data... does not work in live mode_ - perhaps his XML contains some binary characters that aren't visible to you in the downloaded file?

Comment: @NetMage the data is only sensitive and not confidential. I just would not want it available for people to be able to search and find easily. Regrading your second point, as I mentioned, my encoded string of the exact same XML file works and displays the XML in the preview.

Comment: Except your and his encoded string is different, which means either you are using different encodings, _or the files are different_ .

Comment: You could look at the source code of that web site and see how they do it. Maybe you can gain some valuable insight from this. It seems to happen in a function called liveParse in the file site.js (use pretty print in Google Chrome Devtools).

Comment: @Marius, will do.

Comment: How are you transferring the Bae64 string?  Usually errors like this are due to not receiving all the data that was sent.  Start by comparing the length of string at transmitting end with length at receiving end.  Then find out where you are loosing characters.

Comment: @NetMage He's using UTF8 and at least the code of his that I have seen matches the code that I use in my unit test for making sure the XML documents are being decoded/encoded correctly. Also, the XML document that is downloaded when I submit his encoded string is a literal char for char match to the file I receive when decoding my encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

**Try replacing every exclamation point character '!' with a forward slash character '/'.**

I have seen base64 encoded data with exclamation marks in it before. Usually it was embedded in HTML or was intended to be embedded in HTML. Presumably, because forward slashes are a syntactically meaningful character in HTML, and because base64 encoded data can have forward slashes in it, **all the forward slashes have been replaced by an exclamation point.**

I've seen people who have embedded WebAssembly programs in javascript tags do this.

As an additional note, if you have a piece of base64 encoded data, especially one that might be truncated or only part of the full base64 encoded string, and the framework is giving you an exception like the one above or an exception that says "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string", you can try either removing characters from the end of the string, one-by-one, trying to decode it each time (up to about 4 characters or so--beyond that its probably not a length/padding problem), or by adding padding characters '=' (equals symbol) one-by-one, but not more than twice (for a total of two equals, ie '==').